# Error en aplicacion, Heroku Logs FavIcon.ico

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

les cuento, estoy teniendo un error en mi proyecto de reactJs desplegado en heroku. que la verdad no entiendo. dejo el logs a ver si alguien me puede ayudar :)

```
Application Logs
2020-03-26T21:30:24.756697+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pielfagre-manager.herokuapp.com request_id=a17faa09-9a0f-42f5-9698-5cecbf663ea2 fwd="201.253.89.119" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=173 protocol=https
2020-03-26T21:30:27.357995+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pielfagre-manager.herokuapp.com request_id=8d8acc21-4eec-477b-a506-3d502d1d0869 fwd="201.253.89.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=173 protocol=https
2020-03-26T21:30:30.722693+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/bundle.js.map" host=pielfagre-manager.herokuapp.com request_id=c1a3f3fc-efe3-454d-b3c8-45b5d6053b80 fwd="201.253.89.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=6732 protocol=https
2020-03-26T21:30:31.032596+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.chunk.js.map" host=pielfagre-manager.herokuapp.com request_id=4c91bafd-5ead-40ff-b7de-46305013e8ea fwd="201.253.89.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=55ms status=200 bytes=35187 protocol=https
2020-03-26T21:30:31.385750+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/0.chunk.js.map" host=pielfagre-manager.herokuapp.com request_id=73e8dc7e-90c7-47bc-adf1-405f366a80c2 fwd="201.253.89.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=683ms status=200 bytes=1016374 protocol=https
2020-03-26T21:30:39.661522+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pielfagre-manager.herokuapp.com request_id=5ca86b44-f818-4034-8442-a0410bed0251 fwd="201.253.89.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=877 protocol=https
2020-03-26T21:30:43.211331+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pielfagre-manager.herokuapp.com request_id=4d552f68-4704-4a4e-81f1-33bfe1e03055 fwd="201.253.89.119" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=53ms status=200 bytes=877 protocol=https
2020-03-26T21:30:45.601921+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pielfagre-manager.herokuapp.com request_id=84e5e8a4-763a-460d-845f-61ed6fcbb7c8 fwd="201.253.89.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=877 protocol=https
2020-03-26T21:30:50.002951+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pielfagre-manager.herokuapp.com request_id=c19c8ec2-5b7c-4a33-a94f-fcc525cac67b fwd="201.253.89.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=877 protocol=https
2020-03-26T21:30:52.017194+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pielfagre-manager.herokuapp.com request_id=2f1b13e5-9a07-4f0c-abda-b79de189130b fwd="201.253.89.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=877 protocol=https
```